# How can I reset my Progressbar and give it new values , when it reached its maximum?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I'm making a clicker game , where you tap a button to increase your Energy.
When my Progressbar reaches the Maximum value, it resets and sets the maximum value to the next higher one (everything works as it should be).
But when i tap again, the Progress is increased by the old maximum value but after that it continues normally. 
I dont know how to fix this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int MinPoints = 0;
    public int MaxPointsSSJ = 10;
    public int MaxPointsSSJ2 = 20;
    public int MaxPointsSSJ3 = 50;
    public int Progress;

    private void checker(int currentPoints, int maxPoints, int
newmaxPoints, ImageView anzeige, int bild, ProgressBar pb){
        if (currentPoints == maxPoints)
            maxPoints = newmaxPoints;
            pb.setMax(newmaxPoints);
            anzeige.setImageResource(bild);
            pb.setProgress(currentPoints - maxPoints);
            }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView Anzeige = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final ProgressBar KiAnzeige = (ProgressBar) findViewById  (R.id.progressBar);
        Button MehrEnergie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    KiAnzeige.setMax(MaxPointsSSJ);
    KiAnzeige.setMin(MinPoints);
    KiAnzeige.setProgress(0);
    Progress = KiAnzeige.getProgress();

    MehrEnergie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Progress++;
            KiAnzeige.setProgress(Progress);
            if (Progress == MaxPointsSSJ){
                checker(Progress, MaxPointsSSJ, MaxPointsSSJ2, Anzeige, R.drawable.goku_ssj1, KiAnzeige);
            }
        if (Progress == MaxPointsSSJ2){
            checker(Progress, MaxPointsSSJ2, MaxPointsSSJ3, Anzeige, R.drawable.goku_ssj2, KiAnzeige);
        }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: maybe try to create a new instance of the ProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

Set your progressbar inderminate state, So that it will show progress infinite.

```
KiAnzeige.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MehrEnergie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ++Progress;
            KiAnzeige.setProgress(Progress);
            if (Progress == MaxPointsSSJ){
                checker(Progress, MaxPointsSSJ, MaxPointsSSJ2, Anzeige, R.drawable.goku_ssj1, KiAnzeige);
            }
        if (Progress == MaxPointsSSJ2){
            checker(Progress, MaxPointsSSJ2, MaxPointsSSJ3, Anzeige, R.drawable.goku_ssj2, KiAnzeige);
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnClick` function is incrementing your progress bars progress by 1, but in your `checker` function, you are setting your progress bar progress to 0, effectively because currentPoints equals maxPoints.

So in `OnClick`, it looks like 1/10, 2/10, 3/10, ... 10/10, and then that triggers `checker`, which sets it to 0/20, and then it goes back to `OnClick` where it continues as 11/20, 12/20, 13/20, ... etc.

You can fix this by changing your maximum to the difference between the new maximum value and the old maximum value and then setting Progress back to 0, or by accounting for the difference when setting the progress.

Or, if you want the progress bar to "widen" so that the previous clicks are still shown, but the scale of the progress bar is increased, you can just set the progress to `currentPoints` in the `checker` function.